# MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe attempting to connect with h2 instead of SQL

Tags: sonarqube

The first 2 stages (prep, build) of an analysis from the command line with MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe seem to work fine.

The properties in SonarQube.Analysis.xml are:

```
<Property Name="sonar.host.url">http://server-45:9000</Property>
<Property Name="sonar.login">admin</Property>
<Property Name="sonar.password">admin</Property>
<Property Name="sonar.jdbc.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server-46/SonarQube;instance=INSTANCE01;SelectMethod=Cursor</Property>
<Property Name="sonar.jdbc.driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</Property>
<Property Name="sonar.jdbc.username">sonarqube</Property>
<Property Name="sonar.jdbc.password">stackoverflow</Property>
```

The final stage fails with:

```
17:30:17.358 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
```

It appears to be ignoring the local xml settings file completely, finding the default one where the exe is **which is identical** and still trying to create a default h2 connection to a database.

Full log:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary9>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end  
Default properties file was found at C:\Apps\MsSonarRunner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\Apps\MsSonarRunner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary9\ClassLibrary9\ClassLibrary9.csproj
The SONAR_RUNNER_HOME environment variable is not required and will be ignored.
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
Calling the sonar-runner...
C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary9\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin\..
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_60 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows 8 6.2 amd64
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary9\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary9\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary9\.sonarqube\out\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.2
17:30:17.096 INFO  - Load global repositories
17:30:17.295 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=200ms
17:30:17.296 INFO  - Server id: 20151005162012
17:30:17.298 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\me\.sonar\cache
17:30:17.304 INFO  - Install plugins
17:30:17.350 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
17:30:17.358 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.817s
Final Memory: 8M/245M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:30:17.415  Creating a summary markdown file...
```

Anyone any ideas here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

This was a side effect of the following:

I copied batch files from another analysis over and the /s switch pointed to a completely different settings xml file. Doing the pre build run and the post build run with 2 different sets of settings causes this confusion.